# UWP SplitView Issue After Installing Visual Studio 2015.1

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, uisplitviewcontroller, uwp

After installing update 1 for Visual Studio 2015, SplitView control for UWP broken on Windows 10. As you know, SplitView have 2 sub items, an object grid and pane.

**Now, an XAML error says that, "You cannot insert a object into SplitView".**

> [image]

I'm trying move object grid outside of SplitView. It is running at this case. However, the grid could not fitting the UI.

**In addition to this, when I try adding new SplitView control to the page, it thrown a NullReferenceException.**

> [image]

I have not any issues like that on VS 2015 RTM. Are anyone encountered with this issue ? 
Thanks...

**My XAML Code is here:**

```
 <SplitView x:Name="MenuViewer" Margin="0" OpenPaneLength="200" PaneBackground="{StaticResource BorderColor}" RequestedTheme="Light" DisplayMode="CompactOverlay" FontSize="16" PaneClosing="MenuViewer_PaneClosing">
                <SplitView.Pane>
                    <Grid x:Name="PanelGrid" ManipulationCompleted="PanelGrid_ManipulationCompleted" ManipulationMode="TranslateX">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="48"/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid x:Name="MenuButtonGrid" Margin="0" Background="{StaticResource Dark Main Color}" RequestedTheme="Light">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Button x:Name="HamburgerButton" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE700;" Background="Transparent" Click="HamburgerButton_Click" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" RequestedTheme="Light" FontSize="16" Width="48" Height="48"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="MenuText" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,12" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Menu" Foreground="White" RequestedTheme="Light" FontSize="16"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid x:Name="MenuStack" Margin="0,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.Transitions>
                                <TransitionCollection>
                                    <EdgeUIThemeTransition Edge="Bottom"/>
                                    <EntranceThemeTransition/>
                                </TransitionCollection>
                            </Grid.Transitions>
                            <StackPanel x:Name="UserDetailPanel" Orientation="Vertical">
                                <Image x:Name="UserImage" Source="ms-appx:///Images/ProfileHolder.png" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="0"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="UserName" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" FontSize="16" Margin="10,0" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                                <Border x:Name="LogoutBorder" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"  Margin="0,10,0,0" PointerEntered="LogoutBorder_PointerEntered" PointerExited="LogoutBorder_PointerExited" PointerPressed="LogoutBorder_PointerPressed" BorderBrush="{StaticResource TextColor}" >
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="LogoutText" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Logout" Foreground="#FF777777" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Border>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <ListView x:Name="MenuList" ItemsSource="{Binding Menu}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListView_TripItemTemplate}" FontSize="16" SelectionChanged="MenuList_SelectionChanged" Margin="-10,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                            <ListView x:Name="MenuList_2" ItemsSource="{Binding Second_menu}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListView_TripItemTemplate}" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" SelectionMode="None" Margin="-10,0,0,48" Grid.Row="2" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </SplitView.Pane>
                <Grid x:Name="Main" Background="{StaticResource Background}" ManipulationMode="TranslateX" ManipulationCompleted="Main_ManipulationCompleted">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="48"/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid x:Name="Header" Margin="0" Background="{StaticResource Dark Main Color}">
                        <Grid.Transitions>
                            <TransitionCollection/>
                        </Grid.Transitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="64"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="64"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Button x:Name="HamburgerButton2" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE700;" Background="Transparent" Click="HamburgerButton_Click" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontSize="16" RequestedTheme="Light" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        <Button x:Name="AddButton" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE710;" Background="Transparent" Click="AddButton_Click" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontSize="16" Grid.Column="3" RequestedTheme="Light" Width="64" Height="48"/>
                        <AutoSuggestBox x:Name="SearchBar" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0" PlaceholderText="Search" FontSize="16" Style="{StaticResource AutoSuggestBoxStyle_TripLog}" BorderThickness="0" QuerySubmitted="SearchBar_QuerySubmitted" Background="#B2E9E9E9">
                            <AutoSuggestBox.QueryIcon>
                                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Find"/>
                            </AutoSuggestBox.QueryIcon>
                        </AutoSuggestBox>
                        <Button x:Name="Search_Button" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE71E;" Background="Transparent" Click="Search_Button_Click" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="White" FontSize="16" Grid.Column="2" RequestedTheme="Light" Width="64" Height="48" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="Operation_Header" Margin="10,12" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Test" FontSize="16" Foreground="White" RequestedTheme="Light" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid x:Name="MobileSearch_Grid" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Collapsed">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="48"/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <AutoSuggestBox x:Name="SearchBar_Mobile" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,5" PlaceholderText="" FontSize="16" Style="{StaticResource AutoSuggestBoxStyle_TripLog}" BorderThickness="0,0,0,13" QuerySubmitted="SearchBar_QuerySubmitted" Background="#B2E9E9E9"/>
                    </Grid>

                </Grid>
            </SplitView>
```

Comment: I have my split view content wrapped in `<SplitView.Content> ... </SplitView.Content>`. Maybe that is why I don't have this issue.

Comment: Could you post your whole xaml code here? If you don't use `<SplitView.Content>` explicitly, `SplitView` will use the rest part in it as its `Content`. If you only have one `Grid` after `SplitView.Pane`, it should work. You may try to clean and rebuild your project to see if the problem still there.

Comment: Clean & ReBuild does not work. I have not any issue like that when using Visual Studio 2015 RTM. It started with Visual Studio 2015 Update 1. I think that it is a serious bug comes with this update. I add my XAML code via answer option, thanks.

Comment: I tested your code in my side with Visual Studio 2015 Update 1, there is no error. Hava you tried testing your project in another computer with Visual Studio 2015 Update 1?  As you have no issue when using Visual Studio 2015 RTM, I think there may be something wrong with your Visual Studio after updating. And as a friendly reminder, you can post your code by editing your question. Adding it via answer is not a good behaviour.

Comment: Thanks Jay, I did it. Yes you are right, when building, the app running perfectly. I have a problem with XAML designer in Visual Studio 2015 Update 1. Also, I cannot still understand why SplitView control gives "NullReferenceException" error while drag & drop it to into a grid (You can see in the screenshots). This is only broken control. I do a clean install for Windows 10 10586 & Visual Studio Update 1 too after encountering this issue, it did not work.

Comment: I created a feedback. Can you vote, please ? https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2082442/uwp-splitview-problem-on-windows-10-after-applying-update-1

Comment: I can also drag & drop SplitView in my side. From the screenshot you posted, the `NullReferenceException` error is thrown at `Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.Tools` which seems also related to the XAML designer. You can build a new blank project and try to drag & drop SplitView to seem if it still has the same problem.

Comment: I try opening new project too. Gives same error :(

Comment: How can I repair the XAMl Designer @JayZuo-MSFT ?  SplitView.Content tag does not work for me. The XAML viewer shows the U now after using it. However, I cannot interfere the UI objects on Page Explorer. It shows only Page item.

Comment: Have you tried to repair the visual studio from control panel?

Comment: Of course, it not help me.

Comment: Do you use build 10586 (Threshold 1) or 10240 (RTM) for Windows 10 ? I'm trying to determine that this issue will be caused from build 10586... As you read, I have not any issue like that on build 10240.

Comment: I re-install VS also. I try both Enterprise and Community Edition. To addition this, I re-install Windows 10 Pro X64 several times. 
`<SplitView.Content>` tag resolves the  **"You cannot insert a object into SplitView"** error. However, I cannot interfere the SplitView's content now. XAML designer allows me interfere only Pane section. Also, SplitView control in XAML toolbox gives **"NullReferenceException"** in every project while drag & drop.  Unfortunately, I still could not figure out this bug....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer which comes from Microsoft Connect solves my issue. Thanks for contiributions.

> Hi.
>
> We have worked with the Windows SDK team to get this fixed in a future
>   version of the Windows Software Development Kit. We have a workaround
>   that should fix the issue for you. Please "repair" the install, by
>   opening "Add or remove programs," and repairing the "Windows Software
>   Development Kit" matching the version 10.0.10586.15.
>
> Thank you!
>
> Jeremiah